# jQuery nextAll until the following class

Tags: jquery

So I'm trying to assign `.subs` to the previous `div` but I was only able to assign only one that go after the preceding `div`.

I can't figure out how to assign all `.subs` after the `.right` until the next `.right`

Here is the example to get an idea

```js
$(".right").each(function() {
  var a = $(this).find('ul li:last-child');

  $(this).next('.subs').insertAfter(a);
});
```

```css
.right {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px margin-bottom: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="right">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="subs">
  <div class="right">
    <ul>
      <li>Subs One</li>
      <li>Subs Two</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="subs">
  <div class="right">
    <ul>
      <li>Subs One</li>
      <li>Subs Two</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="subs">
  <div class="right">
    <ul>
      <li>Subs One</li>
      <li>Subs Two</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [`.nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) is what you're looking for. This returns all the following siblings up to, but not including, an element that matches the selector.

```js
$(".right").each(function() {
  var a = $(this).find('ul li:last-child');

  $(this).nextUntil('.right').insertAfter(a);
});
```

```css
.right {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px margin-bottom: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="right">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="subs">
  <div class="right">
    <ul>
      <li>Subs One</li>
      <li>Subs Two</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="subs">
  <div class="right">
    <ul>
      <li>Subs One</li>
      <li>Subs Two</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="subs">
  <div class="right">
    <ul>
      <li>Subs One</li>
      <li>Subs Two</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I must go nuts. I already tried it and it didn't work and now it works. Thanks a lot!